# How to beat the time challenge in the first level of Dale and Peakot?

Tags: dale-and-peakot

Any tips on how to beat the time challenge in the first level of Miniclip's [Dale and Peakot](http://www.miniclip.com/games/dale-and-peakot/ro/) game? I've done it on all the other levels, but on the first one, 35 seconds seems quite implausible. I've tried finding a walkthrough, but so far, I've only found videos for another (possibly beta) version of the game - the one where you must collect feathers. The levels differ, so the videos aren't that relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say having all the gun upgrades and the ability to create an ice platform/block is essential.
The first two scarecrows can then be destroyed with one shoot. The last one can be bypassed by creating a ice platform and jumping over it.
The stack of boxes is probably also best bypassed jumping over it, I ended up shooting it but I think this lost me about a second or so.